# 401 Error accessing Azure AD protected API with react-adal

Tags: reactjs, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, adal

I am trying to set up an app with a react front end + a .NET Core back end in Azure with Azure AD Auth. The back end will call other APIs and hold some logic. I set up the .NET Core app and hosted it in an Azure app service, then added authentication using [the connected services wizard in visual studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/vs-active-directory-add-connected-service), which generated code similar to what is on [this tutorial](https://itnext.io/a-memo-on-how-to-implement-azure-ad-authentication-using-react-and-net-core-2-0-3fe9bfdf9f36) (back end section):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddAzureAdBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
...
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
...
}
```

appsettings.json (fake IDs):

```
"AzureAd": {
    "ClientId": "1fff1098-3bc0-40d9-8cd0-e47b065085b6",
    "Domain": "mytenant.onmicrosoft.com",
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "mytenantid",
    "AppIDURL": "https://my-api.azurewebsites.net/",
    "ConfigView": "API"
}
```

Then I set up react-adal on my front end with:

```
{
  tenant: "mytenant.onmicrosoft.com",
  clientId: "1fff1098-3bc0-40d9-8cd0-e47b065085b6",
  endpoints: {
    api: "1fff1098-3bc0-40d9-8cd0-e47b065085b6"
  },
  cacheLocation: "localStorage"
};
```

Which I set up according to the [github instructions](https://github.com/salvoravida/react-adal) to set up react-adal. The sign in works as expected but when I run adalApiFetch against my back end, I get a 401 error with description = the signature is invalid. I can see on the debugger that the authorization header (Bearer + token) is sent. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

The endpoint I'm testing with is a simple test controller (with [Authorize]) that simply returns "Authentication Tested".

Comment: Could you inspect the token at e.g. `https://jwt.ms`? You'll want to check the token contains the things you expect.

Comment: I did, I inspected it in jwt.io originally but it does look like a normal valid token for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find my mistake after a while and came back to post the solution. The problem was that I was using the incorrect method/settings (not matching). From the question's code: If using `sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;` then you should also use AddJwtBearer with the appropriate configuration options (found here: [JwtBearerOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbeareroptions?view=aspnetcore-2.2)) and not AddAzureAdBearer. In my case, the final corrected startup code was

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd",options));
....
```

With corresponding settings (found here: [AzureADOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.azuread.ui.azureadoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.2))